# Using Kendo UI to produce a dynamic page using an array of objects

Tags: json, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

I am working on making a mobile news app. I have 25 stories (just the title) pop up in a list on the first page. Then there are 9 other pages similar to that but seperated by category. 
I want to link each story to pop up as the full article, without using an in-app browser. I want to create a article page which is dynamically produced a JSON object.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
{
    "ALLarticles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title for 1",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. Curabitur fermentum, turpis sed porta ultricies, nulla leo volutpat nulla, eget facilisis lectus quam vitae leo. Duis et ante erat. Suspendisse quis commodo neque. Pellentesque lorem mauris, convallis vitae ultricies et, scelerisque ac massa. Ut lobortis mi quam, sit amet rutrum neque ultricies nec. Curabitur congue mauris vitae varius pellentesque. Maecenas in rutrum mauris, non sollicitudin ante. Praesent at blandit ante, sed commodo ex. Nulla vulputate lobortis urna, a placerat urna consectetur at. Ut vitae iaculis nulla, nec sagittis magna. Suspendisse faucibus consequat magna id tincidunt.</p><p>Donec vehicula porta est sit amet sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Integer nec mauris ac nulla efficitur rutrum. Vivamus feugiat massa id ipsum fringilla vestibulum. Nam eget cursus eros. Donec tincidunt elementum arcu, non rhoncus quam hendrerit sit amet. Ut placerat dui a tortor hendrerit sollicitudin. Maecenas dapibus mi diam, quis molestie tellus elementum vel. Suspendisse porttitor lectus sed malesuada fermentum. Quisque facilisis faucibus justo ac varius.</p><p>Aliquam laoreet lorem in libero facilisis, vel porttitor purus aliquet. Duis egestas pharetra lectus, ac tristique nulla tempor eget. Donec in dignissim libero, ut cursus massa. Maecenas condimentum suscipit bibendum. Curabitur ut lacus id nunc gravida ultrices sit amet ut dolor. Aenean ipsum nibh, varius feugiat nisi eu, dapibus dapibus justo. Nulla accumsan pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse faucibus magna nisi, a fermentum lectus placerat vitae. Nullam eu metus vitae lectus volutpat ultrices vitae sagittis arcu.</p>",
            "date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Some A. Person"
            },
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Title for 2",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. Curabitur fermentum, turpis sed porta ultricies, nulla leo volutpat nulla, eget facilisis lectus quam vitae leo. Duis et ante erat. Suspendisse quis commodo neque. Pellentesque lorem mauris, convallis vitae ultricies et, scelerisque ac massa. Ut lobortis mi quam, sit amet rutrum neque ultricies nec. Curabitur congue mauris vitae varius pellentesque. Maecenas in rutrum mauris, non sollicitudin ante. Praesent at blandit ante, sed commodo ex. Nulla vulputate lobortis urna, a placerat urna consectetur at. Ut vitae iaculis nulla, nec sagittis magna. Suspendisse faucibus consequat magna id tincidunt.</p><p>Donec vehicula porta est sit amet sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Integer nec mauris ac nulla efficitur rutrum. Vivamus feugiat massa id ipsum fringilla vestibulum. Nam eget cursus eros. Donec tincidunt elementum arcu, non rhoncus quam hendrerit sit amet. Ut placerat dui a tortor hendrerit sollicitudin. Maecenas dapibus mi diam, quis molestie tellus elementum vel. Suspendisse porttitor lectus sed malesuada fermentum. Quisque facilisis faucibus justo ac varius.</p><p>Aliquam laoreet lorem in libero facilisis, vel porttitor purus aliquet. Duis egestas pharetra lectus, ac tristique nulla tempor eget. Donec in dignissim libero, ut cursus massa. Maecenas condimentum suscipit bibendum. Curabitur ut lacus id nunc gravida ultrices sit amet ut dolor. Aenean ipsum nibh, varius feugiat nisi eu, dapibus dapibus justo. Nulla accumsan pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse faucibus magna nisi, a fermentum lectus placerat vitae. Nullam eu metus vitae lectus volutpat ultrices vitae sagittis arcu.</p>",
            "date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Some A. Person"
            },
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Title for 3",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. Curabitur fermentum, turpis sed porta ultricies, nulla leo volutpat nulla, eget facilisis lectus quam vitae leo. Duis et ante erat. Suspendisse quis commodo neque. Pellentesque lorem mauris, convallis vitae ultricies et, scelerisque ac massa. Ut lobortis mi quam, sit amet rutrum neque ultricies nec. Curabitur congue mauris vitae varius pellentesque. Maecenas in rutrum mauris, non sollicitudin ante. Praesent at blandit ante, sed commodo ex. Nulla vulputate lobortis urna, a placerat urna consectetur at. Ut vitae iaculis nulla, nec sagittis magna. Suspendisse faucibus consequat magna id tincidunt.</p><p>Donec vehicula porta est sit amet sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Integer nec mauris ac nulla efficitur rutrum. Vivamus feugiat massa id ipsum fringilla vestibulum. Nam eget cursus eros. Donec tincidunt elementum arcu, non rhoncus quam hendrerit sit amet. Ut placerat dui a tortor hendrerit sollicitudin. Maecenas dapibus mi diam, quis molestie tellus elementum vel. Suspendisse porttitor lectus sed malesuada fermentum. Quisque facilisis faucibus justo ac varius.</p><p>Aliquam laoreet lorem in libero facilisis, vel porttitor purus aliquet. Duis egestas pharetra lectus, ac tristique nulla tempor eget. Donec in dignissim libero, ut cursus massa. Maecenas condimentum suscipit bibendum. Curabitur ut lacus id nunc gravida ultrices sit amet ut dolor. Aenean ipsum nibh, varius feugiat nisi eu, dapibus dapibus justo. Nulla accumsan pulvinar ultrices. Suspendisse faucibus magna nisi, a fermentum lectus placerat vitae. Nullam eu metus vitae lectus volutpat ultrices vitae sagittis arcu.</p>",
            "date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Some A. Person"
            },
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/image.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have the html produced as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="articleList-template">
        <div class="articleImg #: id #" style="background-image: url( #:thumbnail# )">
        </div>
        <h2 class="articleTitle">#: title#</h2>
        <h3 class="articleAuthorDate">
         by <span class="articleAuthor">#: author.name#</span> on <span class="articleDate">#: date #</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="articleContent">#: content #</div>
</script>
```

I need to be able to link my list links to this page. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for, but linking a list item to a details page of sorts is very easy.
Listview documentation http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/index

Here is a small sample using your json with a page for headlines, and a page to show the details of that story.

http://jsbin.com/fabexo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: How would I go straight to the page instead of the pop up that says " view story and mark as read "?

Comment: Small change to the list data-bind, and the called function.  http://jsbin.com/fabexo/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am now back on track

Comment: I have another question relating to calling the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451679/how-can-i-create-an-object-within-an-object-when-pulling-remote-json-kendo if you can help that would be awesome.

Comment: I am having two problems now with this method: I cant refresh the lists, and also if I go back to the list and pick another article, It doesn't open back up at the top of the page.

Comment: I fixed the problem of scrolling to the top by adding 
                app.scroller().reset(); right after 
                app.navigate(detailsPage.toString()); but I still cannot figure out how to use the refresh button